# Updating a Project on GitHub Without Having Git Installed

Tags: git, github

My GitHub repository is sinked with my personal laptop. I am working on some projects at work and want to add them to GitHub.

My work PC does not have Git installed (and cannot have it installed).

I added a work project to my GitHub account manually by creating a new repository and then clicking the + sign to create new files for each file. I manually pasted the code into each file.

My question is, when I make an update to my local files, how do I add those changes to the repository that I created on GitHub?

I can't use Git or the GitHub Desktop software.

Do I click on the "Edit this file" button and enter the changes manually? Will all changes be tracked so that I can go back to previous versions?

Comment: It's pretty difficult to use git if you cannot install it. Your only option really is to use GitHub's web UI to make changes to files. But that of course does not scale and is not really a solution. You won't be able to test your changes or create a single commit with changes to multiple files. It's not intended for real work. You really should try to get git installed.

Comment: Please try to make sure that your title accurately represents your question. Instead of "GitHub with Multiple Computers" (which doesn't explain your question at all) perhaps something like "Updating a project on GitHub without having Git installed" would be better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Do I click on the "Edit this file" button and enter the changes manually? Will all changes be tracked so that I can go back to previous versions?

==> yes, changes will be tracked into the git history of your github account.

Your company policy doesn't allow git so you are in difficult situation. 
The solution you mention will work but it is very fastidious so you shoud consider other ones. Maybe :

- working in your local files then make your commits when you come back at home (but working with branches during the day will be impossible, but working with several clones in several folders ...)
- or you could find a server you could connect over ssh, rdp or else, to make your git works..

However, of course, you'll feel really free when you'll succeed to make git installed at work.

Comment: Yours is the only answer that addressed that I CAN'T install Git. I think I'll go with the first option you mentioned. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome @amylynn83, I hope you'll find a good compromise to work in good conditions.

Answer (score 1):

If your work PC does not have Git installed and cannot have it installed than I suggest you do not attempt to interface with Git through Github's webpage. Hand modifying files through "edit this file" or "create a file" on the webpage is not intended to be used for more than a quick fix.

You should see if you can install Git locally and follow a guide to learn the ropes or seek an alternative VCS.

**Note:** Github has great documentation for guides that can be found [here](https://guides.github.com/)